# Pandas conditional indexing - Why do the parentheses matter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, conditional-statements

Why does it matter if I use parentheses or not, with conditional indexing?

I was doing an exercise on Kaggle and my code is identical to the correct varient, except the parentheses that separate the conditional values. But even without separation, to Python it should still be clear, that they are 2 separate conditions.

Am I missing something?

[(kaggle screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5WRH.png)

```
top_oceania_wines = reviews.loc[reviews.country.isin(["Australia", "New Zealand"]) & reviews.points>=95] #my solution

top_oceania_wines = reviews.loc[(reviews.country.isin(['Australia', 'New Zealand'])) & (reviews.points>=95)] #correct solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more info on your variables to better explain.

But looks your first statement is evaluating `reviews.country.isin(["Australia", "New Zealand"]) & reviews.points` and then comparing it with `95`

while your second statement is logically `and` of the two conditions